# How to select Google search bar using CSS selector?

Tags: css, web, css-selectors

The CSS code for the Google search bar is

```
<input id="input" type="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL" aria-live="polite">
```

But I am unable to select it using

```
input[type="search"]
```

What should be the code to select the Google search bar. You can test it in your browswer.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your input in CSS:

```css
input[type="search"]{
  //styles
}
```

**Example:**

```css
input[type="search"]{
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL" aria-live="polite">
```